# Cannot upload files to Azure General purpose V1 type storage account

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I have a General Purpose V1 type storage account. I'm trying to upload a file to a container within this account in Azure portal and get the below error.

> Block blob commit to blob store failed. Details: StatusCode = 400, StatusText = >Blob access tier is not supported on this storage account type."

I understand that V1 type storage account does not have tier (hot/cold) capabilities, so I would like to know how I can upload a file to V1 type account? The upload dialog in the portal has hot, cold & archive and it looks to be a mandatory parameter.

Note: I was able to upload files successfully until few days back.

Comment: Hi, have you meet this error before?

Comment: No, haven't seen this error before. I was upload files until few days back.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code. Also tell us which version of SDK are you using?

Comment: No SDK. I'm trying to upload via the Azure portal into the container.

Comment: No, it is no matter with the SDK.

Comment: Looks like a bug in portal to me.

Comment: Seems like a bug or problems not fixed before.

Comment: Is this forum visible to Azure support for action?

Comment: If you're on Twitter, you can reach out to them there. Their handle is @azuresupport.

Comment: I had the same issue but was able to upload it from `Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer`. Uploading from Portal from MS Edge gave the same error.

Comment: This is an azure portal issue, It doesn't matter. You still can upload files by using code. Problem comes from portal add a `access tier` to form, but v1 type Storage doesn't support that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reproduce your error,

[image]

But this doesn't matter, you still can upload files using code. This seems something error with portal. It give a properties named `access tier` to 'hot'. But v1 type Storage doesn't support the 'hot' access tier(you know this feature). When you upload from code. This situation will not appear.

Comment: I was able to upload using the Storage Explorer tool. As you say, SDKs should also work. The problem seems to be only with the portal.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same issue this morning, after messing around with my other accounts I realised that only the v1 storage accounts were giving this error.

The solution for me was upgrading the storage account to V2: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-account-upgrade.

1. Sign in to the Azure portal.
2. Navigate to your storage account.
3. In the Settings section, click Configuration.
4. Under Account kind, click on Upgrade.
5. Under Confirm upgrade, type in the name of your account.
6. Click Upgrade at the bottom of the blade.

Comment: Thanks. But upgrade to V2 comes with a cost. I was able to upload to V1 until few days back. There was no information that files will not be up loadable to V1.

Comment: @museshad, can you try it with azure storage explorer?

Comment: @Ivan Yang- I get the same err in storage explorer as well

Comment: @museshad, try to create a new storage account v1, set location to "east us", it works at my side.

Comment: @Ivan Yang- Thanks for clarifying that it works in a different region. We have this storage account for a while, can't move easily.

Comment: @museshad, which browser are you using? try use edge browser.

Comment: Thank You @Sbo666 . It worked perfectly. I upgraded to V2.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also suffering by this issue today. I'm using `azcopy` to copy files from a StorageV2 to StorageV1. I solved this issue by adding `--s2s-preserve-access-tier=false` parameter. For example:

```
azcopy cp "https://[storagev2account].blob.core.windows.net/[container]/?[SAS]" "https://[storagev1account].blob.core.windows.net/events?[SAS]" --recursive=true --s2s-preserve-access-tier=false
```

Answer (score 0):

Folks, Thanks for bringing it to our attention. We are rolling out a hotfix to fix this issue. In the interim, please use this URL to unblock yourself: https://portal.azure.com/?feature.canmodifystamps=true&Microsoft_Azure_Storage=lastknowngoodbuild

Answer (score 0):

**Update: Issue has now been resolved.**

A hotfix was deployed, i tested and it's working as normal again.

**Work Around:**

I reported the bug internally as well, Please use Azure Storage Explorer for the time being, I tried and it currently works: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/storage-explorer/

Let me know if this helps, I'll keep you posted once a solution is rolled out.

Answer (score 0):

@Keith: Please try the URL I provided now. It should work, we've verified the LKGBuild URL should work: https://portal.azure.com/?feature.canmodifystamps=true&Microsoft_Azure_Storage=lastknowngoodbuild

Answer (score 0):

The Hotfix was deployed yesterday and you should no longer see this issue on the Portal (even if you don't use the LKG URL I provided yesterday).